# Conditioned two groups of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have two groups of checkboxes: Products and Countries. What I'm trying to do is to have two conditions:

- Case 1: 1 country + many products
- Case 2: many countries + 1 product

So, If I select 2 products I should be able to select only 1 country. If I select multiple countries I should be able to select only 1 product.

Currently, it doesn't work as expected. When I check on the product and then check the second, the first product gets deselected and all become disabled. About the countries - I'm able to select all of them.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/816obeLj/

Here is what I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxCountrySelection = 1;
  var maxIndicatorSelection = 1;

  var countryCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"].countryCheckbox');
  var indicatorCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"].indicatorCheckbox');

  countryCheckboxes.change(function() {
    var selectedCountries = countryCheckboxes.filter(':checked');
    var selectedIndicators = indicatorCheckboxes.filter(':checked');

    if (selectedCountries.length > maxCountrySelection) {
      countryCheckboxes.not(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      countryCheckboxes.prop('disabled', false);
    }

    if (selectedIndicators.length > 0) {
      indicatorCheckboxes.not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      indicatorCheckboxes.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });

  indicatorCheckboxes.change(function() {
    var selectedCountries = countryCheckboxes.filter(':checked');
    var selectedIndicators = indicatorCheckboxes.filter(':checked');

    if (selectedIndicators.length > maxIndicatorSelection) {
      indicatorCheckboxes.not(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      indicatorCheckboxes.prop('disabled', false);
    }

    if (selectedCountries.length > 0) {
      countryCheckboxes.not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      countryCheckboxes.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: _"When I check on the product and then check the second, the first product gets deselected"_ - yes, of course it does - the 2nd checkbox is the one that triggers the change handler, and then you un-check and disabled everything, that is `indicatorCheckboxes.not(this)` - so that's your 1st, 3rd and 4th checkbox then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue in the JsFiddle was that the country checkboxes did not have the `countryCheckbox` class in the html.

Additionally, the js logic could be simplifed as in this working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0macgsw9/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxCountrySelection = 1;
  var maxIndicatorSelection = 1;

  var countryCheckboxes = $('.countryCheckbox');
  var indicatorCheckboxes = $('.indicatorCheckbox');
  var checkboxes = $('.countryCheckbox, .indicatorCheckbox');

  checkboxes.change(function() {
    var selectedCountries = countryCheckboxes.filter(':checked');
    var selectedIndicators = indicatorCheckboxes.filter(':checked');

    if (selectedCountries.length > maxCountrySelection && selectedIndicators.length >= 1) {
      indicatorCheckboxes.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      indicatorCheckboxes.prop('disabled', false);
        }

      if (selectedIndicators.length > maxIndicatorSelection && selectedCountries.length >= 1) {
      countryCheckboxes.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      countryCheckboxes.prop('disabled', false);
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Am not that familiar with JS yet. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name^=country], [name^=product]').change(function(){
        if($('[name^=country]:checked').length > 1){
          $('[name^=product]').attr({'type':'radio'});
        }else{
          $('[name^=product]').attr({'type':'checkbox'});
        }
        if($('[name^=product]:checked').length > 1){
          $('[name^=country]').attr({'type':'radio'});
        }else{
          $('[name^=country]').attr({'type':'checkbox'});
        }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="germany">germany</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="italian">italian</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="french">french</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="orange">orange</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="apple">apple</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="banana">banana</label>
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't though of this way.